# $\frac{301 \times 16}{7} = ?$ How to estimate the answer?

Tags: arithmetic, estimation

[image]

Though  we can get it's exact number , we have to estimate the result.

**My Attempt:** $301 \approx 300$ and $\frac{16}{7} = 2\frac{2}{7} \approx  2\frac{2}{8} = \frac{9}{4} $

So $\frac{301}{\frac{7}{16}} \approx \frac{300  \times 9}{4} = 675$

Can anyone give any better method?

Comment: Please pay attention to your tags.

Comment: Okay sure. Thank you for editing.@TobyMak

Comment: You can easily verify that $301\div 7=43$, and to multiply $43\cdot 16$ isnt a problem at all. This is taught in primary school, so I do not see the point of using an estimate here.

Comment: $301$ is approximately $280$, and $16$ is approximately $15$. The answer is approximately $\frac{280}{7} \cdot 15 = 40 \cdot 15 = 600$. Or $301$ is approximately $300$, and $\frac{7}{16}$ is approximately $\frac{1}{2}$. The answer is approximately $300 \cdot 2 = 600$. Both estimates are underestimates by quite a bit.

Comment: The thing is that when you see that 280 is divisible by 7, which is "common sense", you also can see that 280+21=301 is divisible by 7 and calculate the correct answer.

Comment: is "excellent number sense" some procedure described in your study material somewhere?

Comment: This is a problem to teach how to estimate. I know I can get the exact result easily. @Cornman

Comment: Personally I know the factorization of $301$ by heart since it makes for a nice number theory problem given that $301 \equiv 1 \mod{1,2,3,4,5,6}$, but $301 \equiv 0 \mod{7}$

Comment: I do not doubt that you (improve and sani) can factor this, but simply how senseful this question is to use an estimation for so simple numbers. It kind off makes no sense to use a estimation when every number involved is an integer anyways. For example the estimation of 600 is off by alot. If you want to practice estimation, then do it with examples, where you can not calculate the correct answer more easily, then get a wrong (estimated) result in a complicated fashion.

Comment: It does not refer to any method called Excellent Number Sense. @AlvinLepik

Comment: The problem makes more sense when you swap the $\div$ by multiplication $\cdot$. If it reads $301\cdot\frac{7}{16}$, you could estimate by $320\cdot 7/16=20\cdot 7=140$. This would be a much more senseable question.

Comment: I presume "excellent number sense" is a spell invocation in Harry Potter. So just wave your wand.

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea what "excellent number sense" is, but if you showed me that calculation and said "you have 3 seconds to estimate the result", my estimate would be "about $630$".

My reasoning would be

> Welll, $\frac{7}{16}$ is a little less than a half, so dividing by it will multiply the number by a little more than $2$. Twice $301$ is $602$, so a little more than that is $630$.

Comment: It does not refer to any method called Excellent Number Sense.@5xum

Comment: Considering time as a factor here, makes the problem more interesting indeed.